# Como embaralhar todas as letras das palavras dentro de um arquivo .txt

Tags: python, random

Estou criando um programa que embaralhe todas as letras das palavras dentro de um arquivo .txt em que a cada linha há apenas uma palavra.

Exemplo de um .txt (que chamei de wordlist.txt):

```
batata
limonada
áfrica
```

Como espero que seja o output:

```
atabat
adaoilmn
ficára
```

O que eu tentei fazer:

```
import random


with open('wordlist.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readline()
    list = list(lines)
    random.shuffle(list)
    result = ''.join(list)
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
limonada
batata
áfrica
```

Na minha tentativa, o programa apenas embaralha a ordem com que as palavras são apresentadas.

Meu objetivo é que a ordem em que as palavras são apresentadas mantenha-se as mesmas, mas com cada palavra tendo suas letras embaralhadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

São dois probleminhas aí:

Você confundiu o comando "with" com um "for": o "with", apesar de exigir um bloco de código, o bloco é executado uma única vez. Então, só a primeira linha é lida, e o programa acaba.

Pelo resultado que você descreveu, deve estar chamando o `.readlines()` (com "s" no fim) do arquivo, e não o ".readline" que leria apenas a primeira linha e iria embaralhar a primeira palavra.

Com o "readlines", é criada uma lista em que cada linha do arquivo é um item,e  essa lista é embaralhada.

Outra coisa é que você está chamando sua variável de `list`. A linguagem permite que você faça isso, mas depois que executar a primeira vez, a chamada original de `list`, que constrói uma lista a partir de uma sequência, é sobre-escrita pela sua variável. Você precisa usar outro nome para essa variável.

Então, como o comando `with` realmente só é necessário em programas mais complexos, para evitar vazamento de memória e recursos - e o `for`, se for passado um arquivo já lê um arquivo linha a linha, o seu programa pode ficar assim:

```py
import random


for line in open('wordlist.txt', encoding='utf-8'):
    line = list(linha.strip())
    random.shuffle(line)
    result = ''.join(line)
    print(result)
```